Synchronising Two Video Parts of a Guitar Duet
I am practising both parts of a guitar duet, and would like to record each on camera, to then create a final composite video with both parts played in separate halves of the screen. I normally practice with a metronome app anyway, and so for each video part I thought I might try using one of my bluetooth earphones so the viewer wouldn't hear the clicks.
But how would I synchronise the two videos? I can use the ffmpeg command line tool for video compositing, or could learn to use an open source GUI application, but it's the basic approach to synchronisation I'd like advice on. The piece is quite fast and so I assume viewers would notice if the two parts were out of sync by even a small amount. Do I trust my ear, and iterate? Or is there another method I could use? Perhaps a way to somehow record the metronome on another track(?) of each video file which could be recognised and used by the video compositing software somehow?

There’s a video production stack that might have some good ideas for you.

Thanks, I hadn't noticed it before.

Here's one possibility, which doesn't need any changes to how you record.
For each track you record:

Listen to the metronome on your Bluetooth earphone.  (The microphone needn't pick this up; probably best if it doesn't.)
Following the beat from the metronome, clap once, loudly, a certain number of beats before you will start playing.  (A clap gives both a sudden sound and an accompanying visual that are easy to time exactly and match up later.)  It can be a large number of beats, as long as you use the same number for each track.

Then, in ‘post-production’:

For each track, identify the exact time offset of the clap.  (For example, you could extract the audio and look at it in an audio editor such as Audacity; that should let you identify the time down to 1/100th of a second at most.)
Use those times as offsets when combining the tracks, so that the claps exactly coincide.  Then so should the rest of the audio.  (ffmpeg has options for offsetting each track by a given time.)
Trim the start of the combined file to remove the clap.

If you're recording both audio and video in the same device, then this should cause the video to match up as well.  If not, you could identify the clap time by eye in the video tracks as well, and use that to sync them in the same way as the audio.

As long as you record each part to the same click, 'wild synch' will be OK on today's digital gear. There are free video editors that will let you line up the two video tracks like two tracks in a sequencer, and slide them against each other to get them in synch.  You can set up a 'clapper' and a pre-count if you like, but it should be easy enough to just do it by ear.
